# XML sorting by element name; need an XSL transform

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to sort an XML element by his children elements:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<declaratieUnica luna_r="1" an_r="2011" d_rec="0" nume_declar="aa" prenume_declar="bb" functie_declar="contabil" xmlns="mfp:anaf:dgti:declaratie_unica:declaratie:v1">
  <angajator cif="15548207" rgCom="J40/8813/2003" caen="5221" den="CNCFR CFR" adrSoc="BUCURESTI,str.PIATA GARII DE NORD nr.1" telSoc="              0" faxSoc="              0" adrFisc="aaa" telFisc="123" faxFisc="4567" mailFisc="a@gmail.com" casaAng="_T" tRisc="0.297" dat="1" totalPlata_A="1830">
    <angajatorA A_codOblig="412" A_codBugetar="5502XXXXXX" A_datorat="444" A_deductibil="0" A_plata="444" />
    <angajatorA A_codOblig="411" A_codBugetar="5502XXXXXX" A_datorat="879" A_deductibil="0" A_plata="879" />   
  </angajator>
  <asigurat idAsig="1" cnpAsig="1610830297298" numeAsig="BUCUR" prenAsig="ION" dataAng="01.01.2011" casaSn="_B" asigCI="1" asigSO="1">
    <coAsigurati tip="S" cnp="2680502297316" nume="BUCUR" prenume="MARIA" />
    <asiguratD D_1="B1114" D_2="578" D_5="01.12.2010" D_6="01.12.2010" D_7="11.12.2010" D_9="01" D_10="2" D_14="5" D_15="5" D_16="10" D_17="15685" D_18="131" D_19="119.7328" D_20="449" D_21="449" />
    <asiguratB1 B1_1="1" B1_2="0" B1_3="N" B1_4="8" B1_5="0" B1_6="168" B1_7="0" B1_8="0" B1_9="0" B1_10="1360" B1_15="11" />
    <asiguratB2 B2_1="0" B2_2="11" B2_3="0" B2_4="0" B2_5="911" B2_6="0" B2_7="0" />
    <asiguratB3 B3_1="10" B3_2="0" B3_3="0" B3_4="0" B3_5="0" B3_6="10" B3_7="337" B3_8="0" B3_9="0" B3_10="0" B3_11="337" B3_12="449" B3_13="449" />
    <asiguratB4 B4_1="11" B4_2="0" B4_3="1360" B4_4="7" B4_5="911" B4_6="50" B4_7="1248" B4_8="131" B4_14="0" />
  </asigurat>
  <asigurat idAsig="2" cnpAsig="1790228297307" numeAsig="ADET" prenAsig="FLORIN" dataAng="01.01.2011" casaSn="_B" asigCI="1" asigSO="1">
    <coAsigurati tip="S" cnp="2790427297338" nume="ADET" prenume="ALINA IOANA" />
    <asiguratD D_1="BBBZ" D_2="014578" D_5="01.12.2010" D_6="01.12.2010" D_7="11.12.2010" D_9="01" D_10="1" D_14="4" D_15="0" D_16="4" D_17="14573" D_18="131" D_19="111.2443" D_20="445" D_21="0" />
    <asiguratB1 B1_1="1" B1_2="0" B1_3="N" B1_4="8" B1_5="0" B1_6="168" B1_7="0" B1_8="0" B1_9="0" B1_10="1740" B1_15="17" />
    <asiguratB2 B2_1="0" B2_2="17" B2_3="0" B2_4="0" B2_5="1295" B2_6="0" B2_7="0" />
    <asiguratB3 B3_1="4" B3_2="0" B3_3="0" B3_4="0" B3_5="0" B3_6="4" B3_7="135" B3_8="0" B3_9="0" B3_10="0" B3_11="135" B3_12="445" B3_13="0" />
    <asiguratB4 B4_1="17" B4_2="0" B4_3="1740" B4_4="9" B4_5="1295" B4_6="71" B4_7="1430" B4_8="150" B4_14="0" />
  </asigurat>  
</declaratieUnica>
```

Must be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<declaratieUnica luna_r="1" an_r="2011" d_rec="0" nume_declar="aa" prenume_declar="bb" functie_declar="contabil" xmlns="mfp:anaf:dgti:declaratie_unica:declaratie:v1">
  <angajator cif="15548207" rgCom="J40/8813/2003" caen="5221" den="CNCFR CFR" adrSoc="BUCURESTI,str.PIATA GARII DE NORD nr.1" telSoc="              0" faxSoc="              0" adrFisc="aaa" telFisc="123" faxFisc="4567" mailFisc="a@gmail.com" casaAng="_T" tRisc="0.297" dat="1" totalPlata_A="1830">
    <angajatorA A_codOblig="412" A_codBugetar="5502XXXXXX" A_datorat="444" A_deductibil="0" A_plata="444" />
    <angajatorA A_codOblig="411" A_codBugetar="5502XXXXXX" A_datorat="879" A_deductibil="0" A_plata="879" />   
  </angajator>
  <asigurat idAsig="1" cnpAsig="1610830297298" numeAsig="BUCUR" prenAsig="ION" dataAng="01.01.2011" casaSn="_B" asigCI="1" asigSO="1">
     <coAsigurati tip="S" cnp="2680502297316" nume="BUCUR" prenume="MARIA" />
    <asiguratB1 B1_1="1" B1_2="0" B1_3="N" B1_4="8" B1_5="0" B1_6="168" B1_7="0" B1_8="0" B1_9="0" B1_10="1360" B1_15="11" />
    <asiguratB2 B2_1="0" B2_2="11" B2_3="0" B2_4="0" B2_5="911" B2_6="0" B2_7="0" />
    <asiguratB3 B3_1="10" B3_2="0" B3_3="0" B3_4="0" B3_5="0" B3_6="10" B3_7="337" B3_8="0" B3_9="0" B3_10="0" B3_11="337" B3_12="449" B3_13="449" />
    <asiguratB4 B4_1="11" B4_2="0" B4_3="1360" B4_4="7" B4_5="911" B4_6="50" B4_7="1248" B4_8="131" B4_14="0" />
    <asiguratD D_1="B1114" D_2="578" D_5="01.12.2010" D_6="01.12.2010" D_7="11.12.2010" D_9="01" D_10="2" D_14="5" D_15="5" D_16="10" D_17="15685" D_18="131" D_19="119.7328" D_20="449" D_21="449" />

  </asigurat>
  <asigurat idAsig="2" cnpAsig="1790228297307" numeAsig="ADET" prenAsig="FLORIN" dataAng="01.01.2011" casaSn="_B" asigCI="1" asigSO="1">
```

```
  </asigurat>  
</declaratieUnica>
```

I'm applying this xsl, but does not works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:for-each select="*/declaratieUnica/asigurat">
      <xsl:sort select="name()" />   
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:copy-of select="./."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update from comments**

> In "asigurat" the elements are sorted:
>   asiguratD, coAsigurati are at the
>   end...

Comment: Obs.: In "asigurat" the elements are sorted: asiguratD, coAsigurati are at the end...

Comment: Neither example shows the XSL linking, I just want to be Captain Obvious and rule out the possibility that you forgot to add the stylesheet to your XML file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the following do what you want?

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[edit]
If you want to exclude a child of a certain element from sorting you could use e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:v1="mfp:anaf:dgti:declaratie_unica:declaratie:v1"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="v1:asigurat" priority="3">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="v1:coAsigurati"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::v1:coAsigurati)]">
        <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: But how toput only coAsigurati in the first position (escape him from sorting) ? This is a hard one question :)

Comment: But how toput only coAsigurati in the first position (escape him from sorting) ? This is a hard one question :)

Comment: @Martin Honnen: +1 Correct answer. But `local-name()` instead of `name()` (from the original question) might confuse people making think this is the key change and not the empty iteration (and pattern and xsl:copy-of/@select, etc.). Also `*[*]` it's not the request: *In "asigurat" the elements are sorted*.