# how to sort XML file using java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml file and want to sort like this in txt file

Soccer | England | Premier League | Blackpool FC - Birmingham City 5-1

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>   <LivescoreData>
>   <Sport SportId="1">
>    <Name language="en">Soccer</Name>
>    <Name language="se">Fotboll</Name>
>    <Category CategoryId="34">
>     <Name language="en">Australia</Name>
>    <Name language="se">Australien</Name>
>    <Tournament TournamentId="144">
>     <Name language="en">Hyundai A-League</Name>
>     <Name language="se">Hyundai A-League</Name>
>     <Match MatchId="4616735">
>       ....
>      etc
> ```

Comment: What does "sort like this" mean? What does your XML file look like?

Answer (score 0):

Use [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/).It's a great library for working with xml files.
You can download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dom4j/files/latest/download).

```
    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    Document doc = reader.read(new File("myXML.xml"));
    Element content = doc.getRootElement();
    List<Element> myNeededElements = content.elements("neededElementName");
```

After this you'll have all elements with the name you want (say "neededElementName") in myNeededElements  list.

Answer (score 0):

If you have flexible options in selecting a library/framework, one of the solutions is to use XStream and deserialize the xml into a collection of java objects and sort 'em.

For Ex:

```
List<Employee> employeeList = xStream.fromXML(xmlFile);
Collections.sort(employeeList, new Comparator() { .... });
```

**EDIT**: Also check the below links:

1) [How to sort XML elements in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733614/how-to-sort-xml-elements-in-java)

2) [XSLT Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970474/xml-sorting-by-element-name-need-an-xsl-transform)

Answer (score 0):

Sorting an XML file can generally be done in a few lines of XSLT or XQuery, and invoking XSLT or XQuery only takes a few lines of Java. However, it's totally unclear from your post what your desired input and output are (or at any rate, what relationship they have to each other.)